# How to override theme function in drupal?

Tags: drupal-7

I searched for this but only found results related to .tpl files.I want to override a theme function(for example theme_user_list) from my module.How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to alter the registry using hook_theme_registry_alter() and override the function used. Once you override the *function* index for the function in question and importantly, clear your cache, your module's replacement function - mymodule_foo() - should take effect.

See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7 for more information.

Comment: Thanks. theme_user_list is used by many modules.Is there any way to change the theme for a specific context?for example just for who's online block and not who's new block

Comment: Not that I can tell -- but your implementation may check some variables and then redirect execution to theme_user_list() if none of your customizations are necessary

Comment: I would recommend using hook_theme_registry_alter() only when you are particular about changing the output from your module file. Never create a module just for this. A better way of doing it would be to just add a function '(MY THEME NAME HERE)_func_i_am_overridding()' to your theme > do the changes > clear the theme registry cache.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/group/themeable/7:

> themes utilizing an engine will have
>   their well-named theming functions
>   automatically registered for them.
>   While this can vary based upon the
>   theme engine, the standard set by
>   phptemplate is that theme functions
>   should be named THEMENAME_HOOK. For
>   example, for Drupal's default theme
>   (Bartik) to implement the 'table'
>   hook, the phptemplate.engine would
>   find bartik_table().

So in your case, you can override by creating `MYTHEMENAME_user_list` function.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do this in modules not themes.

Answer (score 0):

You can override theme function for individual output by using suggestions. Do do this, when you call the theme function, append two underscores and a name, then copy the original theme function into your .module file, and rename it MYTHEME_original_function_name__ANAME E.g.

```
<?php
...
$vars['test'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'image_formatter__SOMENAME',
  '#item' => $item,
  '#image_style' => 'large',
);
...
?>

<?php
function MYTHEME_image_formatter__SOMENAME($variables) {
  /* my custom code */
}
?>
```

After caches have been cleared, you should be able to see that in the theme registry, so you then you can user theme_registry_alter to replace it using your module name instead of theme name.

Answer (score 0):

user491844 answer is correct though there is simplier one: edit your theme template.php.

Simply copy the whole original theme function into template.php the replace 'theme' by your theme name in the function declaration. So for example this :

```
function theme_lt_unified_login_page($variables) {[...]}
```

Become this:

```
function MYTHEMENAME_lt_unified_login_page($variables) {[...]}
```

then empty theme registery (or flush all caches).

The only drawback is that all your customisations will accumulate in a single file (template.php) making it not so tidy on large projects.